# How to retrieve app statistics from GooglePlay and Appstore via API?

Tags: api, google-play, app-store, analytics

We need to incorporate into our dashboard information about app installs, uninstalls, etc. Currently, we use Appfigures but it does not cover uninstalls. We would like to use an official Apple and Google API to retrieve app statistics but we cannot find it how to do that. Can you advise?

Mat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google Play it is described [in this page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870). This lets you download statistics from Google Cloud Storage.